# the output of stanford nlp classifier

Tags: stanford-nlp, classification

We are learning the usage of stanford-nlp classifier.  As its wiki page said, it can be used to build model for classifying numerical data like Iris:
http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Classifier#Iris_data_set

But on interpreting the output we have difficult on some of them:  there are 4 columns for input attributes(1-Value, 2-Value, 3-Value, 4-Value) and one column for output label (Iris-setosa, Iris-versicolor, Iris-virginica).  But what is CLASS here?  Is it the output column overall?

Built this classifier: Linear classifier with the following weights

```
        Iris-setosa     Iris-versicolor Iris-virginica 
3-Value -2.27            0.03            2.26          
CLASS    0.34            0.65           -1.01          
4-Value -1.07           -0.91            1.99          
2-Value  1.60           -0.13           -1.43          
1-Value  0.69            0.42           -1.23          
Total:  -0.72            0.05            0.57          
Prob:    0.15            0.32            0.54
```

Answer (score 0):

CLASS is like the intercept term in a simple linear regression - it represents the relative frequency of different classes. It is a feature of every instance.